# Inject outer scope when monkey-patching instance method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, closures, metaprogramming

I have a container class `Foo` with a method `frob`, and I want to add a similarly named method, which will delegate to the container, to each of the contained elements.

First I tried

```
  self.children.each do |c|
    def c.frob
      self.frob
    end
  end
```

but this of course leads to `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`, as `self` is `c` at that point. I then tried

```
  parent = self
  self.children.each do |c|
    def c.frob
      parent.frob
    end
  end
```

but local variables aren't part of the closure of the newly defined method, so I get `undefined local variable or method 'parent'`.

I came up with the following hack, which works:

```
  self.children.each do |c|
    c.instance_variable_set('@parent', self)
    def c.frob
      @parent.frob
    end
  end
```

However, it pollutes the variable space of the child with something that's only needed by this one method. How can I get `parent`/`self` in there while keeping the newly defined method self-contained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
children.each do |c|
  parent = self
  c.send(:define_method, :frob) do
    parent.frob
  end
end
```

Comment: And it gets even cleaner with 1.9+ `define_singleton_method`.